# Writing to /tmp is failing - returning error 22

Tags: ubuntu, tmp

I'm getting this weird behaviour where writing to /tmp is failing.

Even try `touch /tmp/foo` as root fails with `OS error code 22: Invalid argument`.

The permissions are set to 1777/drwxrwxrwt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is `/tmp` mounted?

Alternately, check with `dmesg` to see if there were any kernel errors involving that mountpoint recently.

Comment: It's in /dev - the server is a VPS and other file systems ended up going read-only as well. So I guess it was a SAN failure or something related to the cloud.

Comment: Time to contact the VPS operator, I think.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is to remove /tmp and recreate it

Comment: How does that solve the user's problem?